# Series of user inputs in javascript using readline where corresponding questions are stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach, readline

I've stored few questions in an array `var questions=[]`. I'm using `forEach` to traverse through the array and take input for each and every question and display it on the terminal itself. But it is asking only the first question, displays the response and stays there. It is not shifting to the next question. I should use `rl.close()`, but where. Here is my code `Quiz.js`.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var questions=[
  "Hi, What is your name?",
  "I need your contact number also",
  "Thanks! What is your favourite color?"
];

questions.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  rl.question(item, (answer) => {
    console.log(`You said: ${answer}`);
  });
  rl.close(); //THIS IS IMMEDIATELY CLOSING AFTER THE FIRST QUESTION
}
```

Please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to ask the questions **one by one**, and then `close()` after all questions were asked.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});

let questions = [
    'Hi, What is your name?',
    'I need your contact number also',
    'Thanks! What is your favourite color?',
];

(async () => {
    let answers = [];

    // asking questions one by one
    for (let question of questions) {

        // wait for the answer
        let answer = await new Promise(resolve => rl.question(question, resolve));
    
        console.log(`You said: ${answer}`);
    
        answers.push(answer);
    }

    // close at the end
    rl.close();

    console.log(answers);
})();
```

Comment: This is wonderful. I can see you're using IIFE here. thanks @neverever

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to close it after all questions are asked?

I mean this:

```js
function myFunction(item, index) {
  rl.question(item, (answer) => {
    console.log(`You said: ${answer}`);
  });

  if (index === questions.length - 1) {
     rl.close();
  }
}
```

=== === ===

If it's still not working try this:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

var questions = [
  'Hi, What is your name?',
  'I need your contact number also',
  'Thanks! What is your favourite color?',
];

const ask = (question) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(question, resolve))
}

const askAll = async (questions) => {
  const answers = []

  for (let q of questions) {
    answers.push(await ask(q))
    console.log('You said:', answers[answers.length - 1]);
  }

  return answers
}

askAll(questions).then(rl.close)
```

I closed the `rl` outside the `askAll` function, because I think it's better for the function not to know about such thing as resource management.

Comment: Yes. I did the same thing. But this time it is not even waiting for the input. It simple closes.